# PHP + MySQL connection pool

Tags: mysql, connection, pool

I am searching "db connection pool" support in PHP/MySQL and not able to found any recent document about that. Some people asked this question years ago and the answer was "No". Is there any technique we can do to implemnet "connection pool" in PHP/MySQL?

I only found below information from PHP website.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.pooling.php

There seems not much information regarding pooling implementation on the web.

Comment: create a service that the connection goes only through it and manage pools there

Comment: Try to search "Swoole", a php extension.

Comment: @king thanks, "Swoole" seems nice.